# Passing a nested emitter variable into the callback of an event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

In the following example I need to figure out a way to pass the variable 'id' into the listener of the 'set' emitter. The problem I'm having is that I can't pass it via the handler like updateStore(req.id) because the event 'update' from mongoStore has it's own return value 'mongoId' that it returns, which I also need.

Also, I can't just reference req.id because there's no guarantee that it won't change due to another request coming into app() changing the value. How would I access both the value of req.id and mongoId inside the updateStore handler at the time the handler was initiated?

Please note that this example code doesn't run and it's a stripped down version of a much bigger program. I wanted to provide the logic behind what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
var self = this;
var app = express();
var mongoStore = new MongoStore({url:'/path/to/mongo'});

function updateStore(mongoId) {
    if (mongoId == req.id) {
        // do something
        self.emit('complete');
    }
}

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
    // req.id needs to get passed to updateStore()  
    mongoStore.on('update',updateStore);

    self.on('complete', function() {
        self.removeListener('update',updateStore)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a good look at the javascript [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method

It returns a copy of a given function

- The first argument is the `this` value in the copied function's scope.
- The next arguments are the arguments that will be used in the copied function.

In our case, we can use this method to create a copy of the updateStore function, and use the reference of the `req` object, wrapped in an object literal as the `this` value of that copied function, like this: `updateStore.bind({ req: req })`. That way you just need to access `this.req` inside of it.

```js
var self = this,
    app = express(),
    mongoStore = new MongoStore({url:'/path/to/mongo'});

function updateStore(mongoId) {
    var req = this.req;

    if (mongoId == req.id) {
        // do something
        self.emit('complete');
    }
}

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
    var onStoreUpdated = updateStore.bind({ req: req });

    mongoStore.on('update', onStoreUpdated);

    self.on('complete', function() {
        self.removeListener('update', onStoreUpdated);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!